# SDL 2.0 Issue - Trying to load image, but only get a white box

Tags: image, window, sdl

Okay, so I am trying to load a window and display a couple of images on it using a function. The window loads and my errors don't display for a failure to load the image, however the window just stays white. Any ideas why that might be? This is my code below.

```
 #include "stdafx.h"
 #include "SDL.h"
 #include <iostream>
 #include <string>

 using namespace std;

 const int Window_Width = 640;
 const int Window_Height = 480;

 SDL_Window *window = NULL;
 SDL_Renderer *render = NULL;

 SDL_Texture* loadImage(string imagename) //function that loads the image, useful for handling multiple image imports

 {

SDL_Surface* loadedImage = NULL;
SDL_Texture* texture = NULL;

loadedImage = SDL_LoadBMP(imagename.c_str()); //loads the image with the passed file name

if (loadedImage == NULL) //checks for any errors loading the image
{
    cout<<"The image failed to load.."<<endl;
}

texture = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(render, loadedImage);
SDL_FreeSurface(loadedImage);

return texture;
 }


 int main(int argc, char** argv)
 {

  if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING) == -1)

  {       
    cout << SDL_GetError() << endl;
    return 1;
  }

  window = SDL_CreateWindow("Frogger", SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, Window_Width, Window_Height, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN); 
  //creates a window in the centre of the screen, it uses const int's to define the size of the window

  if (window == NULL)
  {
    cout << SDL_GetError()<<endl;
    return 1;
  }  

  render = SDL_CreateRenderer(window, -1, SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED | SDL_RENDERER_PRESENTVSYNC);
  //this renders the window

  if (render == NULL)
  {
    cout << SDL_GetError()<<endl;
    return 1;
  }

  //loading the images using the function
  SDL_Texture* background = NULL;
  SDL_Texture* frog = NULL;

  background = loadImage("background.bmp");
  frog = loadImage("frogger.bmp");

  SDL_Delay(2000);

  SDL_RenderClear(render);

  SDL_RenderPresent(render);

  SDL_UpdateWindowSurface(window);

  //freeing the memory back up
  SDL_DestroyRenderer(render);
  SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
  SDL_DestroyTexture(background);
  SDL_DestroyTexture(frog);

  SDL_Quit();

return 0;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You aren't rendering anything, you just load some textures and end the program.

Comment: Oh of course. Sorry I didn't see that! Thank you, I'll try that